# How to change native window object type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I want to add a nested object to the native window.navigator object.
But it shows the error:

> TS2687: All declarations of 'navigator' must have identical modifiers.

Looks like it has a conflict with another declaration.
How to modify already declared interfaces?

My **index.d.ts:**

```js
    interface INavigator extends Navigator {
        usb?: {
            getDevices?: () => Array<string>
        }
    }
    
    declare global {
        interface Window {
            navigator: Navigator
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just augment the original `Navigator` interface, it will automatically be merged with and applied to `Window.Navigator`:

```js
declare global {
  interface Navigator {
    usb: {
      getDevices: () => Array<string>
    }
  }
}

const navigator = window.navigator;
const devices = navigator.usb.getDevices();
```